# How to define frozen columns in Cassandra using cqlengine?

Tags: python, cassandra, cqlengine

I'm trying to create a frozen list in Cassandra so that I can use that column as a primary key, I can do that if I run the query manually,

```
some_field frozen <list<int>>
```

but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do it using cqlengine in Python,

```
some_field = columns.List(columns.Integer(), primary_key=True)
```

How can I accomplish the same thing using cqlengine?

EDIT: Final code snippet looks like this,

```
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from cassandra.cqlengine.models import Model

class MyModel(Model):
    __table_name__ = 'my_table'
    __options__ = {'compaction': {'class': 'DateTieredCompactionStrategy',
                              'base_time_seconds': 3600,
                              'max_sstable_age_days': 1}}

    keys = columns.Set(columns.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    columns.BaseCollectionColumn._freeze_db_type(keys)
    time_stamp = columns.DateTime(primary_key=True, clustering_order="DESC")
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [I see in the source code](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/master/cassandra/cqlengine/columns.py#L792), you need to call function `_freeze_db_type` on the instance of the collection type after you created it - this will change type to `frozen<...>`.

Comment: Yes that did the trick, for reference I'm adding the final code on the question,